# Що за "похапець" у "похапцем"?

Tags: етимологія, значення-слів

Читаю в книзі "Хронос" Тараса Антиповича наступне:

> Віднедавна він усе робив якось похапцем, якось злодійкувато, хоча жодного злочину на його двадцятилітньому сумлінні не було, до того ж, він помічав, що цей «похапець» і є новітнім способом життя усього населення, все слід було зробити так, наче за тобою женеться зграя одноногих канібалів...

Розумію, що це може бути неологізм, але цікаво, звідки взагалі йде ця словоформа, окрім, звичайно, слів "похапливо" і "похапливий".

Comment: На Полтавщині, окрім [*похапцем*](http://sum.in.ua/s/pokhapcem) (швидко, поспішаючи), також вживаються утворені аналогічно [*підтюпцем*](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidtjupcem) (дрібними швидкими кроками), [*видавцем*](http://sum.in.ua/s/vydavcem) (міряючи, скупо, ліченими кількостями). І це аж ніяк не неологізми) Посилання на СУМ додаються.

Comment: А, точно, дякую, що нагадали) Ще - *бігцем*, *стовпцем*, і, певно, ряд інших. Тобто, це звичний спосіб словотворення, принаймні, в живому розмовному середовищі в центральній Україні. Не можу стверджувати щодо інших регіонів.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[«Етимологічний словник української мови»](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) Мельничука (том 6 літери «У–Я», стор. 156) містить статтю **хап**, яка стверджує, що це слово походить із старослов'янського *«хапати»*, ймовірно, заснованого на звуконаслідуванні.

Слово **«похапцем»**, разом із іншими похідними словами, також згадується у статті *«хап»*. Там же згадуються слова *ха́па́нка* («крадіжка; хабар; квапливість»), *хапко́* («хабарник; злодій; чорт; і навіть кіт»), *захо́плювач*, *перехопи́ти* та інші.

Корінь **хап-** споріднений з чеським *chápati*, словенським *hòp* та навіть латинським [*capiō*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/capio). Якщо продовжити ланцюжок зв'язків, то можна вийти на ПІЄ¹ `*khap-/khab-`, а звідти, наприклад, на сучасне англійське [**have**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=have&allowed_in_frame=0), а також [*captive*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=captive&allowed_in_frame=0), *capture* та [*capable*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=capable&allowed_in_frame=0).

Отака історія зв'язків слова *«похапцем»*…

---

¹) ПІЄ = правіндоєвропейська мова, умовно-реконструйована мова, яка була в основі більшості мовних груп Євразії.

Answer (score 0):

Це точно не неологізм. http://sum.in.ua/s/pokhapcem
Ще можна згадати «прожогом» (за відсутності іменника «прожог») та деякі інші прислівники, побудовані за схожою моделлю.

Comment: Скажімо так, «похапцем» в ролі прислівника точно не є неологізмом. Але от використання окремого іменника «похапець», може, й можна вважати чимось на зразок використання неологізму, бо, хоча очевидно, що слово «похапець» колись було, але воно майже зникло з мови з тих часів і зараз хтось його може разглядати, наче повторно створене на основі нормативного прислівника (але не кажу, що це правильна точка зору, я не знаю). «Прожогом» — дуже хороша аналогія!